# Closed form of :$S n,m= \sum_{k=1}^n (-1)^k\binom{n}{k}k^{-m!}$

Tags: convergence-divergence, binomial-coefficients

I don't succed to get a closed form of the bellow sum using standard Binomial law , in order to know if this sum could be converge or not for $n\to +\infty$ ,is there any simple way or any algorithm to eavaluate the bellow sum :

$$S n,m=
 \sum_{k=1}^n (-1)^k\binom{n}{k}k^{-m!}$$
?

Comment: It seems _very_ unlikely that this sum has an explicit form. Is your root question about the evaluation, or about proving convergence in some limit? (Also, note that as written, since $m$ only appears in your formula in the form $m!$, you might as well ask about $S_{n,r} = \sum_k(-1)^k{n\choose k}k^{-r}$, taking $r=m!$...)

Comment: For large $n$ the summands do not converge to $0$, I doubt that we may have convergence for $n \to \infty$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The convergence of $S_{n,m}$ can easily be determined when applying the so-called *Dilcher's fromula*

$$
\sum_{1\le n_1\le\cdots\le n_M\le n}\;\prod_{j=1}^{M}\frac{1}{n_j}
 =\sum_{k=1}^{n}\binom{n}{k}\cdot\frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{k^M},
$$

where $M,n\in\mathbb N$ (for more detail, see http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DilchersFormula.html).

Finally, set $M=m!$, $m\in\mathbb N$, to obtain

$$
-S_{n,m}
 =\sum_{1\le n_1\le\cdots\le n_{m!}\le n}\;\prod_{j=1}^{m!}\frac{1}{n_j}
 \ge\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k}.
$$

Consequently, one deduces that $S_{n,m}\to -\infty$ as $n\to\infty$.